# My computer wouldn't shut down so i pulled out mains lead, now my computer won't switch back on. What can i do? Have

Tags: shutdown

My computer was switched on but I lost connection to the monitor, it was blank with just digital and analogue notice in left hand corner so I couldn't shut computer down even when holding in On button. I pulled out mains lead from PC and now it won't work at all. Have I permanently damaged my PC or its it fixable?

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: "won't work at all" is far too vague a description for us to suggest anything other than a repair shop.

Answer (score 1):

Find a bootable USB Key (Windows Install Key, or make a Linux bootable USB key. Try to start with a USB Key. Does it run?  If not, something broke, which caused it not to start.

If the above as all true and it won't run, take it to a local computer shop.